# Need help with this! $\lvert x-y \rvert\lt\epsilon^2 \Rightarrow \lvert\,\lvert\sqrt x \rvert - \lvert \sqrt y \rvert \,\rvert \lt \epsilon$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $\Bbb R$, $ \epsilon \gt 0$. Prove that any positive $\Bbb R$
$$\lvert x-y \rvert\lt\epsilon^2 \Rightarrow \bigl\lvert\lvert \sqrt x \rvert - \lvert \sqrt y \rvert \bigr\vert \lt \epsilon$$

I'm trying to get this done all and I get is an dead end, such as squaring everyone up

$\left( \ \vert \ x-y \ \vert \ \right)^2\lt\left( \ \epsilon^2 \ \right)^2 \Rightarrow \\$
$\left( \  x-y \ \right)^2\lt\ \epsilon^4 \Rightarrow \\$
$x^2 - 2xy + y^2\lt\ \epsilon^4$

and that's pretty much it, from here can't go anywhere close to the objective.

Then again tried another aproach which led me to another dead end.

$$\vert \ x-y \ \vert \lt\epsilon^2$$

$$\Rightarrow u = x-y$$

$$\vert \ u \ \vert \lt \epsilon^2$$

$$\Rightarrow -\left( \epsilon^2 \right) \lt u \lt \epsilon^2$$

$$\Rightarrow \epsilon \gt 0$$

$$u \lt \epsilon^2$$

$$x-y\lt\epsilon^2$$

$$\sqrt {x-y}\lt\epsilon$$

$$\left(x-y\right)^{1/2}\lt\epsilon$$

After this I coudn't go any further and I ran out of any ideas, would anyone be kind to show show a proper solution?

Comment: When it states "any positive $\mathbb{R}$", what is it stating to be positive? $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Have you tried using $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})= x-y$?

Comment: $x \ge 0 \ and \ y \ge 0$

Comment: Then instead of squaring, I suggest trying to use the product of conjugates that I wrote in the above comment. You should be able to show the contrapositive, that, since $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative:$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\ge \epsilon \implies \\|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|\ge  \epsilon^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm gonna work on it and post my answer or doubts, but surely I'm thankful for your tips!

Comment: @Joe Please make this an anwer. That is quite neat!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I see something like $a^2 - b^2$ in these kind of problems, I often try to see if factoring it into $(a-b)(a+b)$ is fruitful.

In this problem, we do not have $x^2 - y^2$, but we do have $|x - y|$ and also $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|$, which suggested to me that using $|x - y| = |(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})|$ might be fruitful.

In this problem, if $x$ and $y$ are both nonnegative, then:

\begin{align}
||\sqrt{x}| - |\sqrt{y}|| &= |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \ge \epsilon \\
& \implies \max(\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y}) \ge \epsilon \label{max}\\
& \implies \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \ge \epsilon \\
& \implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| \ge \epsilon^2 \\
&\implies |x - y| \ge \epsilon^2
\end{align}

Therefore $|x - y| < \epsilon^2 \implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| < \epsilon$

***Edit*** to add more details, as requested:

Since $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ are both greater than or equal to zero, and the distance between them is at least $\epsilon$, then we know that $\max(\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y}) \ge \epsilon $. Otherwise, they would both be in the interval $[0, \epsilon)$, which would make it impossible for the distance between them to be at least $\epsilon$.

Then, since they are both nonnegative, we know that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \ge \max(\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y}) $, hence $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \ge \epsilon$.

So we started with assumption that $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \ge \epsilon$, and deduced (using the nonnegativity of $x$ and $y$) that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \ge \epsilon$, which combine to give:
$$|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| \ge \epsilon^2$$

Since $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| = |x-y|$, that means that we have shown that:
$$|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \ge \epsilon \implies |x - y| \ge \epsilon^2$$
Therefore, we have also shown the contrapositive:
$$|x - y| < \epsilon^2 \implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| < \epsilon $$

Comment: I like it a lot :) also I think this trick occurs so often, that it is really useful to know it

Comment: Back when I was teaching, I always pointed it out as a useful technique to know (in appropriate classes). Unfortunately, I think that sometimes books will not point out how useful the technique is, but give problems that require it, so students get stuck. Then, once the student sees the solution, it may leave the impression that most problems require some unique "trick" to solve them, instead of there being several techniques that are often useful that they should learn.

Comment: I could not agree more. In analysis we use some basic tricks all the time (multiplying by $1$ and adding $0$) and sometimes we forget to put this into perspective.

Comment: I've been trying to understand your approach, but I believe I found myself lacking, could you please explain even more if possible, all I could see is that you went along with contrapositive and I read about as soon you mentioned but I fail to follow along  from the second step bellow stating $max \left(\sqrt x + \sqrt y \right) \ \ge \ \epsilon$, but i did understande the 3rd step as part of the contrapositive argument but after that I wasn't able to understand why or how you reached the 4th step, thank you for your attention!

Comment: I finally got it!
The $max \left(\sqrt x , \sqrt y \right)$ and $\epsilon$ position, just like my teacher once mentioned in class she presented somenthing along the line and showed us $x, y, \sqrt x,\sqrt y, \epsilon, \epsilon^2$ position in a graph (number line) but never really understood the idea and when you combined both terms without disturbing the inequality, $\ge$, I finaly got it how you finally reached $\vert x - y \vert \ge \epsilon$.

Comment: Given my lack of foundation do you have any book recommendation or subjects that I should be looking at before I go any further or something that might help me while I try to progress in Calculus by myself?

Comment: I know you have this question marked with the algebra-precalculus tag, but this is not typically the type of question that would be in a calculus course in any of the colleges that I attended/taught at. This question would be in an introductory analysis course.  I would need to know your level and goal before I could provide a recommendation. If you are trying to learn a first semester course in calculus, I would use one of the standard calculus texts, such as by James Stewart.

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your time and effort, for as my screen name says I'm totally clueless about math, but I did take calculus 1 and 2 and Numerical Analysis, but pretty much of it's gone as years went by, I'm Brazilian by the way, so maybe the way Calculus taught a little different from US or maybe Author's focus is different? But I decided to take it all over again by myself, and James Stewart, I've heard of him before, had one of his books on Physics I guess but sure I can go for his books here, but if you got any recommendation I could just try to have them imported anyway.

Comment: And why no just try Analysis? If I'm that off, it's more of a reason to learn it right? Or maybe one step at a time?

Comment: My recommendation would be based on your goal(s) and current level of understanding. If you do not know calculus yet, I personally would recommend learning that before analysis. I believe the curricula at most, if not all, universities would have calculus courses before analysis courses. Also, is your goal to study math, or become a civil engineer? Are you interested in the theory of calculus, including the rigorous proof of calculus theorems? Your goals and interests are relevant to whether or not you should take the time to study analysis.

Comment: I do intend to follow the text book that was "given" to me at the time, and aforementioned exercise was given even before recap. functions let alone Limits, as for me I intend to study math and never really thought of engineering, as I try to actually understand what I'm doing and why things are the way they are instead of just blindly applying formulas or memorizing rules. But I wish I could somehow apply in programming and everyday tasks. Just hoping I'm not that off.

Comment: I have known several very knowledgeable engineers who knew the material deeply. In particular, there were two graduate students in control systems engineering who took two semesters of functional analysis with me, who knew the material as well as any other student in the class. Depending on which field of math you study, there may be many opportunities for you to apply what you learn to real world problems. Good luck!

Comment: What I meant is that I never thought to pursue a career as engineering, and no, by no means I meant that they'd just blindly apply formulas and such as they have Calculus and many other math related subjects, but that's the way I've been taught and to remedy this it'd make more sense to me to study just math and learn it's way since it's more of a personal goal rather a professional one and I if can make a career out of it the merrier.

Answer (score 3):

Let us suppose that $0\le x< y$. Let $\theta = \frac{x}{y}\in [0, 1)$. We have
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cl}
\cr
&\theta \le \sqrt{\theta}\cr
\Rightarrow &-2 \sqrt{\theta} \le -2\theta\cr
\Rightarrow &1 - 2\sqrt{\theta} + \theta \le 1 - 2 \theta + \theta\cr
\Rightarrow &(1 - \sqrt{\theta})^2\le 1 -\theta\cr
\Rightarrow &(1 - \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}})^2\le 1 -\frac{x}{y}\cr
\Rightarrow &\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x}\le \sqrt{y-x}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
When $0\le y< x$, we just swap $x$ and $y$ to get $\sqrt{x} -\sqrt{y}\le \sqrt{x - y}$. Finally, if $|x-y|<\epsilon^2$, we have
\begin{equation}
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|\le \sqrt{|x-y|}<\sqrt{\epsilon^2}=\epsilon
\end{equation}

Comment: Well first thank you, but am I not supposed to reach $\vert \ \vert  \ \sqrt x \ \vert - \vert \ \sqrt y \ \vert  \ \vert = \epsilon$? Or am I missing the whole idea? Could you please clarify?

Comment: As we assumed in the beginning $0\leq x<y$, we get $\vert \sqrt{x}\vert =\sqrt{x}, \vert \sqrt{y}\vert =\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}=\vert \sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}\vert=\vert \vert \sqrt{y}\vert -\vert \sqrt{x}\vert \vert$. Thus, you get what you want.

Comment: @Clueless see my edits above.

Comment: I did understand the first steps, until I tried to reach for the last step, $\left(1 - \sqrt {\frac xy} \right) \le \1 - \frac xy$, tried to expand it (not sure it's correct term) and reached $2\sqrt {xy} + x \ge x$ and that's no where close to the next step. Could you please clarify that too please?

Comment: I'm using $\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}}\right)^2 = \frac{(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})^2}{y}$